# Cannot save model when using ember render helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm rendering a model into a parent template like this:

```
{{render "teacher" teacher}}
```

Here's it's controller:

```
App.TeacherController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(App.EditableModelMixin, {
    actions: {
        saveTypes: function() {
            if (this.get('model')) console.log('Exists');
            console.log(this.get('model'));
            console.log(this.get('model').get('isFulfilled'));
            this.get('model').save();
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the output when this method is called:

```
Exists
Class {isFulfilled: true, toString: function, constructor: function, reason: null, isPending: undefined…}
true
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'save'
```

This way of doing things has had no problems for me before. It only seems to happen when I use `render`.

**Update**

Here's a screen shot of me looking at the `TeacherController` in Ember Inspector:

[image: TeacherController]

And another of just my view hierarchy:

[image: View]

Comment: Can you show what teacher is in the parent controller, I suspect it might be an item controller

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to do that. How should I go about it?

Comment: I mean, I'm not sure what you mean. I could show you my `model` definition, or a console log, or the ember debugger's print out.

Comment: Here's a pastebin showing a console log, expanded so you can see some important things. http://pastebin.com/zpEM5xsP

Comment: Here's one when printed from ember inspector, also expanded. http://pastebin.com/bhYmttRy

Comment: If I call `console.log(this.get('model').get('id'));` from `saveTypes` it prints the correct id.

Comment: And when I look at the controller in the ember inspector, everything seems fine. I'm working on putting up a screen shot.

Comment: just the property that defines the teacher, or the full template/controller/route that provides teacher to the render helper.

Comment: Here's the complete template that has {{render "teacher" teacher}} in it. It's fairly far down. http://pastebin.com/3YrRSxqs

Comment: No clue? Is this a bug in Ember or something? It seems like it should work fine.

Comment: Sorry, work blocks imgur, had I seen your image yesterday I probably could have helped easier, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as if that model is a PromiseObject (from an async mapping).   Promise objects are an extension of Ember.ObjectProxy which will proxy property calls down to the real model if it exists, but the methods aren't proxied.

```
   var modelPromise = this.get('model');
   modelPromise.then(function(actualModel){
     actualModel.save();
   });
```

Comment: Seriously I'm so happy hahahaha this has been a thorn in my side for weeks.

Comment: w00t, glad to hear!  Gotta love a hard problem that finally makes sense.