# Ember, safe way to save models

Tags: ember.js, couchdb, ember-data

This is a difficult situation to explain, since it's happening so pervasively in my project, but very often when I `save` my models, relationship fields (such as `belongsTo`) simply get erased in the persisted record.

I'm using `couchdb`, so I understand the problem is that each `save` replaces the old version of the record, and if all of the fields aren't sent with the `save` request they won't be in the latest version of the record. That's the problem, that it seems fields aren't correctly populated when the model is `saved`.

Is there a model attribute I can always check that will assure all of it's fields are ready to be pushed? I've tried to write a safe save that always checks `isFulfilled`, but that isn't reliably working. Often times, when I know which field is in danger of being overwritten, I can check for that relationship being fulfilled with a path like `user.isFulfilled`, but that isn't a very general solution, and isn't any good at all if there are *multiple* relationships at risk.

Also, since I'm using [this couchdb adapter](https://github.com/roundscope/ember-couchdb-kit), I have a suspicion that these issues are normally handled by Ember Data but aren't being handled by that package.

I will be happy to provide code if asked! Like I said though, this is a pervasive problem.

#### Edit

I should also let you know my models are defined in a highly asynchronous manner. All of the relationship definitions are very similar to this:

```
user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true})
```

This means that my models very often have `PromiseObjects` of some sort, rather than normal objects. I've dealt with problems like this already ([Cannot save model when using ember render helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846408/cannot-save-model-when-using-ember-render-helper)) but again a more general solution would be great.

#### Edit

Here's what I've come up with:

```
function safeSave(model) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        attributes = [];
        model.eachRelationship(function(name, descriptor) {
            if (descriptor.kind == 'belongsTo') {
                attributes.push(name);
            }
        });

        var checkAttributes = function() {
            if (attributes.every(function(item) {return (model.get(item) === null) || !!model.get(item + '.isFulfilled');} )) {
                Ember.run.once(this, function() {
                    model.save().then(function(record){
                        console.log('Saved successfully.');
                        resolve(record);
                    }, function(error) {
                        console.log('Error while saving.');
                        reject(error);
                    });
                });
            }
        };
        checkAttributes();
        attributes.forEach(function(item) {
            if ((model.get(item) !== null) && !model.get(item + '.isFulfilled')) {
                model.addObserver(item + '.isFulfilled', function() {
                    if (model.get(item)) {
                        model.removeObserver(item);
                    }
                    checkAttributes();
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

It works in some situations, but not others. Is there a more elegant and safe way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, this is due to known issues in Ember Data, such as:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1532

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of it just being a bug. Now to figure out a workaround!